# How to fix List index out of range error?

Tags: python

I am receiving the 'List index out of range,' error from the code below. The aim of the code is to determine values that are present in both lists. I know there are probably more concise ways of writing this code but this was my solution and I would like to know if it is even possible to do it this way.

I tried subtracting one from the length of the arrays (in the 'for' range) to see if that was the issue but it still returned the same error.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
n = 0
n2 = 0
for n1 in range(0, len(a)-1):
    for n2 in range(0, len(b)-1):
        if a[n1] == b[n2]:
            print(a[n1])
            n2 += 1
        else:
            n2 += 1
        n1 += 1
```

If the code worked properly it would print the numbers: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 & 13.

Comment: In your `for n2` loop, you keep incrementing `n1`, so it goes beyond the bounds of `a`. It looks like all of your `+= 1` lines are unnecessary.

Comment: Ohhhh. Thanks for this comment, it helped me realize that my  += 1 line was in the wrong for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
n = 0
n2 = 0
for n1 in range(0, len(a)):
    for n2 in range(0, len(b)):
        if a[n1] == b[n2]:
            print(a[n1])                
        else:
            pass
#Output:
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
```

**Explanation**: The iteration happens between range 0 to length_of_list and the code is comparing values between every value at index `n1` in `a` & values at index `n2` in `b`. You do not need to explicitly increment `n1` or `n2` on every iteration, Python takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're coming from a language like Java, where you mainly iterate over a list or array by accessing elements at indices.

In Python, you can iterate over the elements of a list instead. So in your case, you could write something like

```py
for n1 in a:
    for n2 in b:
        if n1 == n2:
            print(n1)
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this list-comprehension solves what you need :

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
c = [i for i in a if i in b]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code may be a more concise version to achieve your goal:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

ans = []
for n in a:
    if n in b:
        ans.append(n)

print(ans)
```